# CSS integration with HTML

Tags: html, css

I have created a separate CSS file for a tool tip as below.

```
.help-tip{
position: absolute;
top: 18px;
right: 18px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #BCDBEA;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 26px;
cursor: default;
    }

    .help-tip:before{
content:'?';
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
    }

    .help-tip:hover p{
display:block;
transform-origin: 100% 0%;

-webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

    }

    .help-tip p{
display: none;
text-align: left;
background-color: #1E2021;
padding: 20px;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
right: -4px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.4;
    }

    .help-tip p:before{
position: absolute;
content: '';
width:0;
height: 0;
border:6px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
right:10px;
top:-12px;
    }

    .help-tip p:after{
width:100%;
height:40px;
content:'';
position: absolute;
top:-40px;
left:0;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% {
    opacity:0;
    transform: scale(0.6);
}

100% {
    opacity:100%;
    transform: scale(1);
}
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity:0; }
100% { opacity:100%; }
    }
```

From this file calling the .help-tipclass from that in html file as below. I am expecting the tool tip to be shown which is not happening as expected. Earlier I had written css code in same html file under style section but then moved css code to separate file.

```
<div class="domtooltip_style.help-tip">
                     <p><b>Deal-O-Matic (DOM)</b> has implemented multiple controls and safeguards for deal creation to ensure deal quality and to ensure that automatically created   deals meet retail teams’ business requirements.<br>
                     <b>Contribution Profit (CP) Check</b>: DOM ensures that Deals created automatically are CP positive through the duration of the deal and ends deals that turned   CP negative.</p>
                   </div>
```

Appreciate if someone can correct me to call class from CSS file in HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the html you separate multiple classes with a space

so use

```
<div class="domtooltip_style help-tip">
```

Comment: I think better close as typo. this is the trivial and most basic use of CSS ... if not a typo, a ton of duplicates : https://www.google.com/search?q=use+multiple+class+css+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP-KP7gKneAhWDIlAKHdcOCzQQrQIoBDAAegQIBxAO&biw=1600&bih=789

Comment: @TemaniAfif agreed, have also voted to close.